# How to use console serial cable for cisco SG300 switch?

Tags: switch, cisco-sg300

I have cisco SG300-28P series managed switch. I'd like to change default ip which is (192.168.1.254). When I am trying to connect the switch using ethernet cable it is shown me there is no access, even I have put static ip to my laptop in the same default subnet ip.

My question is:
Is there a way to connect the switch without doing reset? 
additional thing, I am seeing console serial port at the back of switch. It is first time to see that console which is looks like serial cable.

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using a serial cable, connect that console port to the serial port on your computer (or a USB adapter), load up a terminal program, set it to <del>19,200</del>115,200 Baud (thx jonathanjo), 8N1 and hit . Other devices use e.g. 19,200 or 38,400 Bd by default.

Comment: Just a comment about baud rate: manual says "115200 bits per second (with release 1.2.5 of the firmware, autobaud detection is enabled by default, so the switch should detect the speed after you press Enter)." https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/sf30x_sg30x/quick_start/78-19252-01.pdf

Comment: Thx @jonathanjo - I was too lazy to look that up actually. ;-)